# Prevent race condition in SQL transactions for Data Integrity

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, race-condition

**Example situation**

I have a bank app that a client subscribes to, help collect contributions.

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
   id BIGINT,
   balance BIGINT
    );

CREATE TABLE transactions(
  tx_id BIGSERIAL,
   amount BIGINT,
   client_id BIGINT,
   customer_id BIGINT
   mode VARCHAR (20)
 );
```

My client has a medium that collects this funds and he has large customer base that contributes every second like 5 contributions per second.

SQL Transaction code executed by this 5 instances concurrently:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO transactions (amount, client_id, customer_id mode)
    VALUES (10.00, 3345, 454, "web");

SAVEPOINT save_tx_cs454;

UPDATE clients SET balance = balance + 10
    WHERE id = 3345 RETURNING balance;

COMMIT;
```

### Problems

- How do I construct my code to make sure that the `UPDATE` to the clients `balance` is done properly. (e.g previous balance is $500 at the end of these statements the available balance would be $550)
- Could I use LOCKS since ROW LEVEL LOCKING is available and how do I do that
- Is there any other way I can implement this or is there a better way to optimise it.

NB: code samples with note would-be preferable for answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your transactions will do the right thing automatically.

If all 5 transactions try to update the same record in `clients`, they each try to take a `ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock on the row. The transaction which happens to come first will get the lock, and the others have to wait until the lock is released, which is at the end of the transaction.

So your updates on `clients` will be serialized, and the end result is guaranteed to be 550.